# gcc: how to write double-precision constants when using -fsingle-precision-constant

Tags: gcc, constants, double, language-lawyer

I am using a gcc command recommended by Maxim which has the `-fsingle-precision-constant` option. (For the purposes of this question, assume I have to use that option, for compatibility with Maxim stuff. Although, I must say, things *seem* to work just fine without that option.) Is there a documented way to write a double-precision constant when using this option?

I have found that appending "L" to the constant *seems* to make it double-precision. For example:

```
double d = 0.123456789123456L;
```

But I did a quick Google search and did not find any documentation for this syntax. As KamilCuk points out, the "L" suffix is documented in the C spec. However, the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath) seems to override it:

> `-fsingle-precision-constant` causes floating-point constants to be loaded in single precision even when this is not exact.

To make sense of the option in the first place, we have to assume that the gcc documentation overrides the C spec. Therefore, in my reading, constants ending in "L" are not exempt from the demotion effected by `-fsingle-precision-constant`.

Is there a documented way to write a double-precision constant when using `-fsingle-precision-constant`?

Comment: `did not find any documentation for this synta` https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant the part `If suffix is the letter l or L, the floating constant has type long double`

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you, that's a great point. However, according to the documentation logic, the gcc option takes precedence. I've updated the description to point this out.